# Is the original Shazam dead?

Tags: dc, shazam

I caught an article that said Billy Batson had the Power of Shazam, and another that said that Shazam is dead, and Billy now has control of the power of Shazam.

Is this true?

Comment: Have you seen the *Shazam!* movie yet?  That might clarify what you've been hearing.

Comment: A lot of rambling removed and I tried to fill in what gaps were left. If there is a source that said Shazam is dead, you should [edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're referring to the original comicbook Shazam, then the answer is a very firm yes. Captain Marvel's origin story was told no less than 6 times in the first 12 years of publication and while there are some slight changes each time, each depiction is in agreement that the [great wizard Shazam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam_(wizard)) imbues Billy Batson with his powers and is **subsequently killed by a falling block of granite.**

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Whiz Comics #2** (1939)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Whiz_Comics_Vol_1_2)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Whiz #47** (1943)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Whiz_Comics_Vol_1_47)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Marvel Family #1** (1945)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Family_Vol_1_1)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Captain Marvel Adventures #80** (1948)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Marvel_Adventures_Vol_1_80)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Captain Marvel Adventures #121** (1949)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Marvel_Adventures_Vol_1_121)</sup></sub>